# Unable to creat PDF output from knitr in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I am not able to create output in Rstudio using knitr package.
I am having this problem for weeks. I am getting  the following error:

```
"Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

In addition I am getting this Warning message:

> running command '"**C:/Users/Krish/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS assignment1.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output assignment1.pdf --template "C:\Users\Krish\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.14.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43**"

Comment: do you have MiKTeX properly installed?

Comment: I have installed it.How to know if it is properly installed?

Comment: You could check if a [minimal LaTeX example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics#The_LaTeX_syntax) compiles.

Comment: No even that is not running.Same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! Please make sure you don't have minor errors in your LaTeX markup. In my example after changing the location of the comma from `$X,$` to `$X$,` my pandoc error disappeared and I was able to render my pdf.